# ERROR: syntax error at or near "FOREIGN" (SQLSTATE 42601)

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I'm trying to add to a column that already exists, in an orders table, the constraint that it is a foring key:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.orders DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS location_id;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.orders
    ADD COLUMN location_id bigint
    CONSTRAINT orders_location_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (location_id)
        REFERENCES public.locations (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the “table constraint” syntax in a column definition. Use the “column constraint” syntax:

```
... ADD COLUMN location_id bigint
        CONSTRAINT orders_location_id_fkey REFERENCES public.locations (id)
```

See the syntax diagram in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

> `ADD [ COLUMN ] [ IF NOT EXISTS ] column_name data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]`
> [...]
> and `column_constraint` is:
>
> `[ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]`
> [...]
>  `REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ] [ MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE ]`
>    `[ ON DELETE referential_action ] [ ON UPDATE referential_action ] }`

Comment: I just made this 
```ALTER TABLE public.orders
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_orders_locations FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES public.locations (id);```

Comment: ... but for that, the column already has to exist. That is different.

Comment: yes, this column already exists.

Comment: In your question it doesn't.